# What is the purpose of those special characters in the sed command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, sed, grep

I found this bash command that creates a directory tree in your console window. I find it quite useful, but I don't really understand how all of the special characters work. Could someone help break it down for me?

```
alias tree="ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'"
```

The first two are pretty simple to understand, this is creating an alias in bash that recursively lists the files and folders beneath the current directory.

```
1. alias tree="" 
2. ls -R
```

But after those I'm pretty much lost. I get that it's piping the rest of the commands through grep and sed, but I don't understand the rest of it or even what these modifiers are called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias tree="ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'"
```

- `ls -R`: list subdirectories recursively
- `grep ":$"`: grep only for lines with `:` at the end of the line
- `sed -e 's/:$//'`: remove `:` at the end of the line
- `-e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'`: replace all path components except of last dir with `--`. To be precise replace any char except of `-` followed by any char except of `/` repeated zero or more times and then followed by `/`.
- `-e 's/^/   /'`: add 3 spaces at the beginning of the line
- `-e 's/-/|/'`: replace first `-` with `|`

There are many "problems" with this snippet starting with parsing of `ls` command, but leaving this aside, you can rewrite `sed` part in more compact way:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//;s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g;s/^/   /;s/-/|/'
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of ls..